# How do I read multiple images into an array in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, pca, face-recognition

I am currently working on a PCA face recognition project and I am wondering how do I read multiple images into a matrix and then resize them to say 50x50. Im aware that I need to use Imread and pass in the images, followed by using imresize.
Would it be something like the following?

```
myFolder = 'C:\Users\X';
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.jpg');
jpegFiles = dir(filePattern);
for k = 1:length(jpegFiles)
baseFileName = jpegFiles(k).name;
fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
imageArray50x50 = imread(fullFileName);
imageArray50x50New = imresize(imageArray50x50, [50 50]);
imshow(imageArray30x40New)
```

Is this a good approach? how would I resize the images correctly?

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have dealt with, the only way to read in multiple images from file is to do it serially and through  a `for` loop.  What you have currently is indeed a good approach, but you need to determine **how** you want to store all of these images in MATLAB.  The two easiest options would be to create a 3D matrix where each slice is a 50 x 50 image you read from file or a cell array where each cell is a 50 x 50 image.

If you want to do the first option, you would do something like this:

```
%// Your code
myFolder = 'C:\Users\X';
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.jpg');
jpegFiles = dir(filePattern);

%// New - 3D matrix to store images
imageMatrix = uint8(zeros(50,50,numel(jpegFiles)));

%// Your code
for k = 1:length(jpegFiles)
    baseFileName = jpegFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
    imageArray50x50 = imread(fullFileName);
    imageArray50x50New = imresize(imageArray50x50, [50 50]);
  
    %// New
    imageMatrix(:,:,k) = imageArray50x50New;
end
```

To access the k<sup>th</sup> image, you would do:

```
img = imageMatrix(:,:,k);
```

The above code is assuming that all of your images are of type `uint8`.  If this isn't the case where your images are of different types, a cell array approach would be preferred.... so that'd be the second approach.  If this is the case, then do this instead:

```
%// Your code
myFolder = 'C:\Users\X';
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.jpg');
jpegFiles = dir(filePattern);

%// New - 3D matrix to store images
imageMatrix = cell(1,numel(jpegFiles));

%// Your code
for k = 1:length(jpegFiles)
    baseFileName = jpegFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
    imageArray50x50 = imread(fullFileName);
    imageArray50x50New = imresize(imageArray50x50, [50 50]);
  
    %// New
    imageMatrix{k} = imageArray50x50New;
end
```

To access the k<sup>th</sup> image, you would do:

```
img = imageMatrix{k};
```

---

However, if you are dealing with PCA, then what I suggest you do instead is create a **2D matrix** where each **row** is the **unrolled** version of the image and you would have as many rows as you have images.  Therefore, each row would be a 1 x 2500 vector of intensities.  The reason why you'd want it like this is because if you were to use the `pca` function in MATLAB, each **row** is a data point while each **column** is a variable.  Therefore, you would do this instead:

```
%// Your code
myFolder = 'C:\Users\X';
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.jpg');
jpegFiles = dir(filePattern);

%// New - 3D matrix to store images
imageMatrix = zeros(numel(jpegFiles), 2500);

%// Your code
for k = 1:length(jpegFiles)
    baseFileName = jpegFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
    imageArray50x50 = imread(fullFileName);
    imageArray50x50New = imresize(imageArray50x50, [50 50]);
  
    %// New
    imageMatrix(k,:) = double(imageArray50x50New(:).');
end
```

Therefore, each row would be an image represented as a single vector.  This statement: `imageArray50x50New(:).'` first converts the 50 x 50 image into a column vector, then it is transposed so that it becomes a row vector.  Also, take notice that I made the image matrix **double** precision.  I did this because `pca` is best suited for floating-point data, and so when I transformed each image into a row vector, I've casted the data to `double` to facilitate this.

Comment: How did you get 250 in `imageMatrix = zeros(numel(jpegFiles), 250);`? Should this be 2500?

Comment: @Mr.rk Thanks. This is what happens when you don't test your code before writing an answer.